# Shell script to read through 2 files and perform rsync operation

Tags: shell-script

Is there any way I can read through 2 files for following values and perform rsync operation to copy files from different hosts & JVMs.

Note: 
We have 2 different hosts whereas JVMs are common across both the hosts, as they run in cluster.

Currently, I have below commands in a shell script . However, I would like to pass the values for Host_Name and JVM_Name through files or read through files.

For e.g.

Host_1

```
rsync -hav -e ssh --info=progress2 user@loggerserver:/xxx/xxxx/host_name_1/logs/JVM_Name_1/logs/messages.log        /cygdrive/d/xxx/xxxx/host_name_1/JVM_Name_1/messages.log
rsync -hav -e ssh --info=progress2 user@loggerserver:/xxx/xxxx/host_name_1/logs/JVM_Name_2/logs/messages.log        /cygdrive/d/xxx/xxxx/host_name_1/JVM_Name_2/messages.log
rsync -hav -e ssh --info=progress2 user@loggerserver:/xxx/xxxx/host_name_1/logs/JVM_Name_3/logs/messages.log        /cygdrive/d/xxx/xxxx/host_name_1/JVM_Name_3/messages.log
rsync -hav -e ssh --info=progress2 user@loggerserver:/xxx/xxxx/host_name_1/logs/JVM_Name_4/logs/messages.log        /cygdrive/d/xxx/xxxx/host_name_1/JVM_Name_4/messages.log
```

Host_2

```
rsync -hav -e ssh --info=progress2 user@loggerserver:/xxx/xxxx/host_name_2/logs/JVM_Name_1/logs/messages.log        /cygdrive/d/xxx/xxxx/host_name_2/JVM_Name_1/messages.log
rsync -hav -e ssh --info=progress2 user@loggerserver:/xxx/xxxx/host_name_2/logs/JVM_Name_2/logs/messages.log        /cygdrive/d/xxx/xxxx/host_name_2/JVM_Name_2/messages.log
rsync -hav -e ssh --info=progress2 user@loggerserver:/xxx/xxxx/host_name_2/logs/JVM_Name_3/logs/messages.log        /cygdrive/d/xxx/xxxx/host_name_2/JVM_Name_3/messages.log
rsync -hav -e ssh --info=progress2 user@loggerserver:/xxx/xxxx/host_name_2/logs/JVM_Name_4/logs/messages.log        /cygdrive/d/xxx/xxxx/host_name_2/JVM_Name_4/messages.log
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking. Do you want to use a shell variable for `host_name`? Something like `.../xxx/xxxx/${host_name_2}/logs/...`?

Comment: Hi Jeff,  Currently I have above resynch commands in shell script running through cygwin. This covers 2 physical hosts and 12 virtual JVMs. But in future if number of hosts  or Virtual JVMs  increases then it would be look weird to have  those many resynch command lines instead . I would like to have some my shell script enhanced by using 2 for loops or  other looping mechanism which can read those host and jvm values through some file and perform resynch.   Hope I am able to describe my question this time

Answer (score 0):

Make a hosts file named `hosts.txt` containing any hosts you want. Then run:

```
for i in $(cat hosts.txt); do for j in {1..4}; do rsync -hav -e ssh
--info=progress2
user@loggerserver:/xxx/xxxx/$i/logs/JVM_Name_$j/logs/messages.log
/cygdrive/d/xxx/xxxx/$i/JVM_Name_$j/messages.log; done; done
```

You can change the numbers in the braces to contain whatever range you want.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much Janken551. This indeed helped me to get the outcome exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton :)